# Extjs 4 Calendar how to implement

Tags: ajax, database, extjs4.1

I would like to implement an Calendar using Extjs 4 (4.1.3), that permits to me keeps dates, with ajax tecnology, from database. I would like that clicking on cell makes appear an editor that permits to me to modify the caratteristic of that date on database and so on.

P.s. : I have tanke a look to that site, http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/calendar/index.html, but i really don't know how to its works and to download the code. BUt it is so difficult to implement that i need?

Tanx.

Answer (score 1):

The example uses the [Extensible Calendar](http://ext.ensible.com/).  It is fairly easy to work with, they include examples and documentation in the download.  They even have a "remote" example that shows a simple example of your scenario.

With that said, it is not free if you are using it in a commercial application (just like ExtJS).  An individual developer license is $199 ($329 with support).

Comment: Hi Justin, I have used it, and try to modify some eventWindow and form..to manage events like CRUD..but i have noticed it is so hardly to manage the framework if it is not close to the original develop.

Comment: I think your best option would be to use the Extensible Calendar and as you encounter specific problems, post specific questions here or on the Extensible forum.